# id isn'tcarrying forward the associated ID image that was selected

Tags: php, html, image

I am trying to get the selected product id's image to move forward to my checkout page, as of now, it carries forward the first product image that I have listed on my main products page.

I have all of my products listed in a foreach loop like this..

```
<?php   
// Loop to display all products
foreach($products as $id => $product) {
?>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="productpiccontainer">
            <?php echo "<img class='productpagesizedimg' src='productpics/".$product['img'] ."' alt='Product Pic'>"; ?>
        </div>      

        <p><?php echo "<a href='./viewProduct.php?view_product=$id'>" . $product['product_name'] . "</a>"; ?></p>
        <p><?php echo "$" . $product['price']; ?></p>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

I am able to get the correct product image when I select on the product. This takes me to a page called viewProducts.php. It works great on this page. I am pulling the product id and image like this..

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products where product_id =".$_GET['view_product']);
if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $products[$row['product_id']] = $row;
    echo "<img class='sizedimg' src='productpics/".$row['img'] ."' alt='Product Pic'>";
}
?>
```

Something I noticed though is that I have this code on the viewProducts.php page..

```
// View Product
if(isset($_GET['view_product'])) {
    $product_id = $_GET['view_product'];
```

And I don't have that in my checkout page. When I try to add the code above to my checkout it breaks everything. I have much more php code in my checkout page and only need that code for the image part, so I tried surrounding it with the image code like this..

```
<?php

// View Product
if(isset($_GET['view_product'])) {
    $product_id = $_GET['view_product'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products where product_id =".$_GET['view_product']);
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $products[$row['product_id']] = $row;

        if($row['image'] == ""){
            echo "<img class='sizedimg' src='productpics/".$row['img'] ."' alt='Product Pic'>";
        }
        echo "<br><br><br><br>";
    }
}
?>
```

With that code, I get a blank spot. The image doesn't show up at all. Is there something I'm not doing right?

UPDATE:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['view_product'])) {
    $product_id = $_GET['view_product'];
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products where product_id =".$_GET['view_product']);
if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $products[$row['product_id']] = $row;

    echo "<img class='sizedimg' src='productpics/".$row['img'] ."' alt='Product Pic'>";

    echo "<br><br><br><br>";
}
?>
```

Error:

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home4/pfarley1/public_html/checkout.php on line 474

For this line

```
if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
```

UPDATE:

When I have the code like this, I get an image to show up, but it is my first product in my database over and over again for the amount of products I have in my cart...

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products");
if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $products[$row['product_id']] = $row;

    if($row['image'] == ""){
        echo "<img class='sizedimg' src='/productpics/".$row['img']."' alt='Product Picture'>";
    } 

}
echo "<br><br><br><br>";
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have `view_product` in your query string? if you add `echo $_GET['view_product'];` before the line `if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {`(which is generating error) what will you get?

Answer (score 0):

```
if($row['image'] == ""){
    echo "<img class='sizedimg' src='productpics/".$row['img'] ."' alt='Product Pic'>";
}
```

Clear one thing in this code is

```
$row["image"]
```

and

```
$row["img"]
```

Both are same or different. Means you miss typed or actually both columns  exists in database and what value these columns have?

Comment: Good catch. I'm not sure why I even had that code in there.. It still isn't working. I changed the code around and now instead of the code being blank, I get this an error. I updated my question.

Comment: Means you have error in query place echo mysqli_error($con); just before if and after if condition.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home4/pfarley1/public_html/checkout.php on line 472............I'm not sure why it is saying line 1? Nothing is wrong there, unless that means it is not pulling something from another page correctly? The other line is the same one I posted in my update.

Comment: I updated my question again, I get an image to show up with that code, but it just displays the first product in my db over and over again for the amount of products in my cart.